# grep -xf does not match the expected output, may be a bug

Tags: linux, macos, shell, grep

I want to print out the same lines in a.txt and b.txt.
I think "grep -xf a.txt b.txt" meets my needs.
But it doesn't work properly.
My system environment is MacOs Mojave

```
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat a.txt
123 abc
123 abc jjj
123
456
zzz
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat b.txt
123 abc
123 abc jjj
123
456def
456
xyz
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ grep --color=never -xf a.txt b.txt
123 abc
123
456
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$
```

the expected output in this case

```
123 abc
123 abc jjj
123
456
```

The encoding of these two files is the same. There is no space at the end of each line.
I thinks the reason is "123 abc" is the prefix of "123 abc jjj"
Then I did two tests.

test1

```
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat 1.txt
a
ab
abc
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat 2.txt
a
ab
abc
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ grep --color=never -xf 1.txt 2.txt
a
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$
```

test2

```
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat 3.txt
abc
ab
a
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat 4.txt
abc
ab
a
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ grep --color=never -xf 3.txt 4.txt
abc
ab
a
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$
```

Is this grep bug or is my usage wrong?

Comment: Your usage is wrong. `grep -x` requires the whole line to match. If you have a prefix that matches, but then other content that doesn't, having that other content means the whole line does not actually match.

Comment: ...btw, it would be a stronger question if it explained *why* you think your stated expected output to be correct.

Comment: thank, I know `grep -x` requires the whole line to match. but the line `123 abc jjj` both in a.txt and b.txt, it should match in the b.txt, but is doesn't output

Comment: I think `grep -xf a.txt b.txt` should works like `egrep -x "123 abc|123 abc jjj|123|456|zzz" b.txt`. And the output of this command `egrep -x "123 abc|123 abc jjj|123|456|zzz" b.txt` meets my expectations.

Comment: I'm geting the expected result on Linux. Are you sure you don't have some trailing space lurking there?

Comment: @JamesBrown I find a linux server and did my test, I got the expected output. `grep -xf` may have bugs on MacOs. I use `grep --color=never` in this test case, because it's also a bug in MAC [grep -f on OS X produces segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247142/grep-f-on-os-x-produces-segfault)

Comment: I'm still unconvinced. A reproducer that creates the input files would give us assurance that they really have the values you think they do (and don't have invisible differences, say, CRLFs rather than LF-only traditional UNIX newlines).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JamesBrown

I find a Linux server and did my test, I got the expected output. `grep -xf` may have bugs on MacOs. I use `grep --color=never` in this test case, because it's also a bug on MacOs [grep -f on OS X produces segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247142/grep-f-on-os-x-produces-segfault)

In this case, I got the expected output on MacOs by doing this.
But I don't know if this is a general solution.

```
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ sort -r a.txt > c.txt
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ sort -r b.txt > d.txt
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat c.txt
zzz
456
123 abc jjj
123 abc
123
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ cat d.txt
xyz
456def
456
123 abc jjj
123 abc
123
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$ grep --color=never -xf c.txt d.txt
456
123 abc jjj
123 abc
123
[yangyue ~/tempDir]$
```

Comment: I used this method to manipulate a large amount of data and found that there were still errors on MacOs. Finally, I wrote a python script to solve the problem.